# How to create a table using two other tables in R?

Tags: r, datatables, data-manipulation

I have two tables. One is called `enrollment`, the other is called `students`.

enrollment

```
student_id   class_id  
004           compsci
010           compsci
002            engli
010            engli
003            engli
```

students:

```
student_id    first_name
  002           Abril
  004           Chris
  010           Davis
  003           Riley
```

I need an output table like below where only the `class_id` and `first_name` appears by a match of `student_id` and `first_name` from the above two tables.

```
class_id   first_name   
compsci      Davis
compsci      Chris
engli        Abril
engli        Davis
engli        Riley
```

Data:

```
enrollment<-data.frame(student_id=(c(004,010,002,010,003)),class_id=(c("compsci","compsci","engli","engli","engli")))
student<-data.frame(student.id=c(002,004,010,003),first_name=(c("Abril","Chris","Davis","Riley")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- student %>% left_join(enrollment,by = c('student.id'='student_id')) %>% select(-student.id)
```

Output:

```
  first_name class_id
1      Abril    engli
2      Chris  compsci
3      Davis  compsci
4      Davis    engli
5      Riley    engli
```

Comment: What about that one student Davis who took both compsci and engli? How to make him appear twice in the output table? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `merge` command, i.e.:

```
colnames(student)[1] <- 'student_id'
joined <- merge(enrollment,student,by='student_id')
joined <- joined[,c('class_id','first_name')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `data.table` approach:

```
setDT(enrollment)[student, first_name := i.first_name, on=.(student_id==student.id)][, -'student_id']    

   class_id first_name
     <char>     <char>
1:  compsci      Chris
2:  compsci      Davis
3:    engli      Abril
4:    engli      Davis
5:    engli      Riley
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` from `base R`

```
enrollment$first_name <- student$first_name[match(enrollment$student_id,
            student$student.id)]
enrollment[c('class_id', 'first_name')]
```

-output

```
#    class_id first_name
#1  compsci      Chris
#2  compsci      Davis
#3    engli      Abril
#4    engli      Davis
#5    engli      Riley
```

Comment: What about that one student Davis who took both compsci and engli? How to make him appear twice in the output table? Thanks!

Comment: @TongClaireXu Sorry, I was checking the output from other solutions.  Updated the post

Comment: @TongClaireXu Based on your input data, first element should match `Chris`